# in search form enter wrong query get's me keyerror with pandas and django

Tags: python, django, pandas

in my basic search form with framework django , when i enter wrong keyword of a drug dataset in my search form gets me wrong like  "KeyError" 
this search form work with pandas lib , so i am just want when i put word wrong do not show me error

i want to show to the user message "nothing match try something else"

this is the error when i put word not in my dataframe the word is Tramadol

[image]

this is my code

```
def search_recommender(request):
 query = request.GET.get('q')
if query:
    indices = pd.Series(df.index, index=df['drugName']).drop_duplicates()
    idx = indices[query]
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:6]
    mov_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
    gg_will = df['drugName'].iloc[mov_indices]
    json = gg_will.to_json(orient='values')
else:
    qs = DrugDataset.objects.all()
    df = qs.to_dataframe()
    json=df.filter(drugName='q')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `try`-`except` to specify that the search was unsuccesful, like:

```
def search_recommender(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        indices = pd.Series(df.index, index=df['drugName']).drop_duplicates()
        try:
            idx = indices[query]
        except KeyError:
            json = 'No match, try something else'
            # ...
        else:
            sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))
            sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
            sim_scores = sim_scores[1:6]
            mov_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
            gg_will = df['drugName'].iloc[mov_indices]
            json = gg_will.to_json(orient='values')
    else:
        qs = DrugDataset.objects.all()
        df = qs.to_dataframe()
        json = df.filter(drugName='q')
```